# how to add mouseover function when mousedown is fired,and remove mouseover function when mouseup is fired javascript

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown' ,md ,true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup' ,mu,true);
    
function md(e) {
    var xcoor= e.screenX;
    var ycoor= e.screenY;
    console.log(xcoor+'md')
        
    window.addEventListener('mouseover' ,mo,true); 
    function mo(e){
        var x2coor= e.screenX;
        var y2coor= e.screenY;
        console.log(x2coor)
    }
}
    
function mu() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousedown',md,false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone doesn't want a thousand mouse events firing off like a machine gun. It's neat to see the console display all of those coords so rapidly but it gets old fast. If you have the mouseup event remove the mousedown event handler, you'd have to write something overly complex to rebind it or reload the page. Kinda limiting.

The example below deals with two event handlers:

| Event Handler | Event | Listener | Purpose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `init(e)` | `mousedown`+ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key | `window` | Bind and unbind the `mousemove` event |
| `evxy(e)` | `mousemove` | `window` | Log: Mouse Events and XY coordinates |

Basically the user can bind and unbind the `mousemove` event by clicking anywhere on the page with the mouse while holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (or <kbd>⌘</kbd> for Mac).

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Bind the Window object to the mousedown event
window.addEventListener('mousedown', init);
// Define a flag
let active = false;

function init(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) { /* If the Ctrl key was pressed when there's a mouse click...*/
    evxy(e); /* ...Run EVentXY...*/
    if (!active) { /*...If the flag is false...*/
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', evxy); /* ...Bind the mousemove event*/
      active = true; /*...and set the flag to true */
    } else { /* Otherwise...*/
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', evxy); /*Unbind the mousemove event*/
      active = false; /*...and set the flag to false */
    }
  }
}

function evxy(e) {
  let ev = e.type;
  let xy = [e.screenX, e.screenY];
  console.log(ev + ': ' + xy);
}
```

```css
.as-console-row::after { width: 0; font-size: 0; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; word-break: break-word; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; max-width: 25%; margin-left: 75%; }
```